# Spanish accented characters in windows-1252 character set

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, windows-1252

I had issues with accented characters(Spanish) in a csv, when open through excel, which was generated using php (not properly displayed). The encoding was utf-8. I have changed the encoding to UTF-8 with BOM. The issue found solved
But.....
We need to upload this csv to a third party software and it does not accepts both the files(first one because of weird chars and second one because of unknown reasons). So now I found that when using the ansi encoding (windows-1252) the characters are displaying properly. 
My question is, can the ansi encoding can represent all the Spanish characters? 
Any other solution to this issue will also do good. 
note: In notepad++ all the three encoding shows proper characters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 – These are all the characters Windows 1252 supports.

Comment: I wanted to know, whether this contains all the Spanish characters.

Comment: What exactly are "Spanish characters"? Do you ever write "smörgåsbord" in a Spanish text, like the English do? Does that make ö and å "Spanish characters"? If and when you decide what "Spanish characters" are, simply look at the list of characters and decide whether all characters you deem relevant are supported.

Comment: I am not good with the Spanish language. What I only know is, there are accented chars used in names and all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#Keyboard_requirements

Comment: that's something helpful.